# Add parameter with no value

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchEmployee
@EmployeeID int,
@EmployeeName nvarchar(256),
@Address nvarchar(256),

AS

Select EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Address 
From Employee
Where
EmployeeID = @EmployeeID OR
EmployeeName LIKE '%' + @EmployeeName+ '%' OR
Address LIKE '%' + @Address+ '%'
```

Then In my Winforms I call it when `comboBox1.Text` = `ALL`

```
using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.SearchEmployee", myDatabaseConnection))
  {
  mySqlCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  if (comboBox1.Text == "ALL")
        {
         mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", textBox1.Text);
         mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", textBox1.Text);
         mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox1.Text);
        }
  }
```

Now how I will do it when `comboBox1.Text` = `EmployeeID`

Something like this : ?

```
      if (comboBox1.Text == "ALL")
        {
         mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", textBox1.Text);
         mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", novalue);
         mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", novalue);
        }
```

Comment: why are you using LIKE on an int column?  That seems crazy dangerous

Comment: as you mentioned. I gonna edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tink you are looking for DbNull.Value (namespace System).

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "EmploueeID")
{
   mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", textBox1.Text);
   mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName",DbNull.Value);
   mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", DbNull.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.DBNull.Value` like this:

```
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", System.DBNull.Value);
```